# Hosting via GoDaddy, Not Displaying Pictures

Tags: html, image, web

Over the past week I've taught myself enough html to code a website and get it on to GoDaddy for hosting. The website is up and running, but it doesn't display any of my photos. All of the photos are photos that I have taken and then uploaded onto GoDaddy along with my html and css files. Sorry if this is a silly question, but I don't understand how to correctly link my photos in the img tag. I've tried changing it a bunch of different ways. Below is one example of my code for these photos looks now.

```
    <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="file:///public_html/images/DSC_2887.jpg" width="500px" /></div>
     </div>
```

I've changed the file to the file it is on the server. Perhaps that's wrong. Anyway thanks so much!

Comment: You are providing wrong path of image.

Comment: Make sure image file is present in the same folder that of your html file, then give path img src="DSC_2887.jpg"

Comment: thanks so much that worked!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the relative path instead of absolute path, like:

```
<div class="parallax-container">
<div class="parallax"><img src="./public_html/images/DSC_2887.jpg" width="500px" /></div></div>
```

Comment: you're welcome, as @Upendra Joshi said, make sure the path relationship between image and html.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization on the file extension seems to matter on GoDaddy. Make sure its exact: .JPEG .jpg .JPG, also try using .png instead.